# Is there an umbrella term for constructor/destructor methods?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, destructor, c++17

Does the standard contain terminology for describing both a `constructor` and a `destructor`?

Is there a technical term or phrase that can encompass the two, but exclude all other kinds of methods?

"Lifetime" methods?

---

I've seen constructors called `"ctors"` and destructors called `"dtors"` but I've never seen `"tors"` used to describe both.  Does such a phrase exist?

Comment: Being lazy, I often use `ctor` and `dtor` abbreviations, but I never considered how to group those into one term. I'd probably end up with `xtor`. But you ask about the standard.. I think it considers them to be a special case of member functions. I dont remember any unique name for such group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the closest you are going to get is *special member function* but this also includes copy/move constructor and assignment , section `12` *[special]* says:

> The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment operator (12.8), move constructor
>   and move assignment operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4) are special member functions [...]

Comment: *Special member function* doesn't include "regular" constructors.

Comment: @T.C. it does not, which is why I started with *I think the closest you are going to get*

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the term "manager methods" used (see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Accessor.2C_mutator_and_manager_methods) as a general term for any function that manages an object.

Comment: This is exactly the term I was looking for.  Even though it's not a part of the language terminology, it fits my model for describing both a constructor and destructor.

Comment: It's not part of the *language* terminology because it's more of the fundamental underpinnings of OO. It's part of the mathematical-theoretical underpinnings behind all object-oriented design, and is applicable to any OOP.